# displaying \u2205 in uitextfield ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitextfield

While working on an already developed project I have to reassign few attributes in core data to default value blank space I used \u2205 and unmarked the option "Optional". To avoid crashes.

Now the problem is it shows this unicode as a text \u2205 in textfield until I get data from service.

How can I get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert unicode like this :

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[self.textField.text UTF8String]];
self.textField.text = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can below code:

```
NSString *inputString = @"\u2205";
NSString *outputString = [NSString stringWithCString:[inputString UTF8String]
                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Your final String : %@", outputString);
```